# Using handcrafted features in CNN

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

What is the difference between using CNN with handcrafted features and CNN without handcrafted features?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CNN automatically extracts features, so hand-crafting features has become unnecessary for most applications.  It learns what features to extract via backpropagation.

You can introduce handcrafted features in a few ways to boost the performance of a CNN:

- inject hand-crafted features into the fully connected layer
- feed the CNN output into another classifier alongside the hand-crafted features

[This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317340604_Handcrafted_vs_Non-Handcrafted_Features_for_computer_vision_classification) explores such concepts.